# Como puedo guardar un pdf Generado con la librerira de html2pdf en el servidor con php

Tags: php

En este caso estoy haciendo uso de la librerira html2pdf

1. Tengo mi html y uso un contenedor con  y clase .contenedor

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      const $elementoParaConvertir = document.querySelector('.contenedor');
      var pdf = html2pdf()
        .set({
          margin: 1,
          filename: 'prueba.pdf',
          image: {
            type: 'jpeg',
            quality: 0.99
          },
          html2canvas: {
            scale: 3,
            letterRendering: false
          },
          jsPDF: {
            unit: "in",
            format: "a2",
            orientation: 'p'
          }
        })
        .from($elementoParaConvertir)
        .save()
        .then(pdfResult => {
          $.ajax({
            url: './controlPDF.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: `pdf=${pdf}`,
            success: function(respuesta) {
              console.log(respuesta);
            }
          })
          console.log('SI HACE PETICION');


        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
        .finally()
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->

  <!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script> -->
  <script src="html2pdf.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="contenedor">
    <!--CONTENIDO PARA CONVETIR A PDF-->
    <h>Contenido</h1>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

2. En este caso me genera un pdf, sin embargo el pdf lo genera del lado del cliente , y yo quiero pasar ese pdf al lado del servidor, guardar el archivo en una carpeta. Desde el servidor con PHP.

```html
<?
$pdf = $_POST['pdf'];
move_uploaded_file( $pdf , 'files/');

?>
```

En este caso yo utilizo php para el lado del back, sin embargo al momento de recibir la peticion no se puede realizar. Cabe aclarar que la peticion tambien ya la hice con un FORM DATA y la recibi en el servidor mediante $_FILES['pdf'], y SI me genera un archivo, pero al momento de abrirlo me genera un archivo vacio sin nada de informacion.